# How to validate string format with scala in compile time

Tags: scala

My function has 1 parameter and type is string but lenght is 4, Can I validate this parameter in compile time?

In haskell and F# have type level and it can validation in compile time, like nonEmptyList.

How to make it in scala. I think shapless can do this but I don't understand

Thank you for advance suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Shapeless can do this. Perhaps something like this:

```
def f(s: Sized[IndexedSeq[Char], Nat._4]): ...
```

You wouldn't be able to pass strings directly to this, though. You'd have to do something like `f(Sized('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't with vanilla Scala.

The best approach you can go is creating a special type for this -

```
  case class SpecialString(string: String) {
    require(string.length == 4)
  }
```

Then, make your function receive `SpecialString` as a parameter instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Using macros is also an option for compile-time validation. See this post by Arnout Engelen: http://blog.xebia.com/compile-time-evaluation-scala-macros/

I've modified his example to define a string-validating function:

```
object CompileTimeStringCheck {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  // This function exposed to consumers has a normal Scala type:
  def stringCheck(s: String): String =
    // but it is implemented as a macro:
    macro CompileTimeStringCheck.stringCheck_impl

  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context 

  // The macro implementation will receive a 'Context' and
  // the AST's of the parameters passed to it:
  def stringCheck_impl(c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._

    // We can pattern-match on the AST:
    s match {
      case Expr(Literal(Constant(nValue: String))) =>
        // We perform the calculation:
        val result = normalStringCheck(nValue)
        // And produce an AST for the result of the computation:
        c.Expr(Literal(Constant(result)))
      case other => 
        // Yes, this will be printed at compile time:
        println("Yow!")
        ??? 
    }
  }

  // The actual implementation is regular old-fashioned scala code:    
  private def normalStringCheck(s: String): String =
    if (s.length == 4) return s
    else throw new Exception("Baaaaaah!")
}
```

Here's the catch, though: This needs to be compiled before it can be used, i.e. put it into a utils jar or something. Then you can use it at a later compile time:

```
import CompileTimeStringCheck._

object Test extends App {
  println(stringCheck("yes!"))
}
```

Again, see Arnout Engelen's post for more details and the original solution (http://blog.xebia.com/compile-time-evaluation-scala-macros/).